# Is it okay to post bountysource links in questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110817/webgl-lens-distortion-reversal-applied-unequally-to-x-and-y-only-works-on-squar) has a bountysource.com link, $40 if you answer the question

Here's a screenshot in case the question is edited

[image]

Does SO have a policy for this? Is one needed? The question itself is poor as it's kind of asking for debugging help but there's no MCVE nor is there enough info in the question itself to answer so I voted to close

But, that's really a separate issue. Assume the question was awesome but there was a bountysource.com link. That seems to end up turning it into a "give me teh codez" type of question which seems like a bad precedent. People could just go delete the link but is there something to point to where in the FAQ/Help or something that such links are NG.

Comment: Do you think the question is *good*, even without the Bountysource link?

Comment: Hah, what a coincidence (I commented on that question before I saw this meta post).

Comment: Monetary bounties are an occasional feature request on meta, and they always get shot down with "this creates the wrong incentives". I don't see why an external bounty would be any better.

Comment: I'm rushing to the conclusion.  Either someone thinks it should be, or someone will invariably *remove* the link.  At that point, what kind of question are we left with?  Would it pass any kind of muster if it didn't have a Bountysource link in it?  Gut says "no" since the code is off on GitHub, and we don't know if/when GitHub's going to be DDoSed again.  Further, it seems like there's more handwaving rather than concrete problem and attempts.  But that's a first glimpse.

Comment: So add it back in.  Does the link then add any substantial value to the actual question?  Does it clarify or narrow the scope in any way?

Comment: I'd say this should be discouraged and / or banned. It unfairly encourages more views / attention to these questions regardless of how good the question is.

Comment: Soon: "Premium SO", ask questions, pay for answers, only 79$/year!

Comment: The question is deleted now, just to let you know

Comment: @Sinatr You're forgetting the Comcast Developer Fastlane Package: $49/mo!

Answer (score 24):

It's simply an unhelpful link.  It doesn't add anything of value to the question.  Feel free to remove it while editing the post.  I don't see any need to involve a moderator here, unless the user is continuing to edit it back in after others edit it out.

Of course, as you mentioned, the question also has other problems, which you can handle just as you would if there weren't a link in the question.

In this case, since the whole question is just so bad (link aside), I wouldn't bother with the editing.  Edit posts that you can actually salvage.  This post seems too far gone to salvage, so I wouldn't bother.  Just vote to close/downvote/delete.  If you disagree and think there's a good question in there, then have at it and edit it into one.

Comment: Is it really *that* bad? It sure looks more substantive than most typical gimme teh codez questions to me. Only thing that stands out about it is way too many links without their content reproduced in the question itself, but does the entire question really have to go away ASAP ("Just vote to [...] *delete*")?

Comment: I think that this answer misses the original topic a bit... The fact that money is in play here and that it draws additional attention to this particular question is not even looked at; only the (bad) quality is topic here...

Comment: @BoltClock It was certainly missing more than just not having any of the code.  If someone told me they could salvage it, I could certainly believe them, but I don't see how it could be done myself.  In addition to not having any code it also seems rather unclear and also seems too broad.  It would certainly take quite a lot to salvage a question like that.

Comment: I do disagree on your point about "don't both editing the post, just vote to close." Something like that which is a detriment to Stack Overflow should still be edited out. You never know when a question takes longer than desired to get deleted.

Comment: @krillgar But that's just is; all that it is is an unhelpful link.  It's not something that need to be urgently removed; simply something to also remove as a part of the process of fixing the question.

Comment: @Servy: While there's nothing wrong with deeming a question unsalvageable to you, if others could conceivably to you salvage a question in a reasonable amount of time, the question should not be deleted ASAP. Votes to delete - particularly if cast immediately after closure - should be reserved for questions too far gone for *anyone* to salvage in any reasonable amount of time; notably, questions that you would have flagged as VLQ (were that still a thing). Let the Roomba take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

We keep telling users that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Of course we usually mean it in the sense that nobody will write the asker's code for free,[<sup>[citation needed]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed) but I believe this is also true in a broader sense. If you need coding help for your work, hire a consultant, or go to codementor or the handful of other sites which I expect to exist to help people pay money for programming work.

People on Stack Overflow donate their free time to answer questions to build <strike>a better future</strike> a knowledge base of programming. If your question fits into this picture, you will get an answer for free. If it doesn't, no amount of money[<sup>[citation needed]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed) should change this, and the question should remain unanswered and/or closed.

We already see how bounties measured in internet points bias users' behaviour, giving rise to sloppy and link-only answers, or fulfilled (too broad) requirement dumps. These all degrade the quality of Stack Overflow in the long run, and placing actual money into the picture won't help a bit.

Comment: @GolezTrol no no no. I meant  "These [bounties posted on low-quality questions that spring up unhelpful answers instead of closures] all degrade the quality of Stack Overflow in the long run". I agree that gamification and rep is an important (key) driver on SO, I'm talking about abusive patterns I see a lot. I don't think it's healthy for the site to start offering money for answers.

Comment: Comment removed. Still, I think bounties are a useful way to draw attention to questions about rare subjects. I've awarded bounties on a couple of questions, including those of others, in an attempt to get an answer that I just couldn't find even after a fair amount of searching. Of course there will be abuse as well, but not so much, since poor questions usually come from low rep users that don't have so much rep to spare on bounties. If SO would introduce payed bounties, I would have them adhere to the same basic rules.

Comment: @GolezTrol in my tags there are several users who ask vague/broad questions, then bounty them to get an answer (which also blocks closure mechanics). The other day I found a user who has been building a daisy chain of "*I have this code from this previous question, how can I make it do the next step*" questions via bounties. I never said that bounties are inherently bad: for difficult questions and/or low-traffic tags these are really useful. But considering how already an enticing sum of rep can lead to deviant behaviour, I'd hate to see the same effect when actual money is on the table.